# Error running agent: starting input inputs.websocket: failed to WebSocket dial: failed to send handshake request: Get context deadline exceeded

Tags: kubernetes, websocket, timeout, minikube, telegraf

the deployment pod in minikube trying to connect to a docker container on 9003 port to gather metrics but getting below error

[telegraf] Error running agent: starting input inputs.websocket: failed to WebSocket dial: failed to send handshake request: Get "http://xxxx-1:9003": dial tcp 10.103.161.32:9003: i/o timeout

tried checking logs in container the image is actually working fine